# Approaches for multi-label classification with over 1,000,000 labels

Tags: deep-learning, classification, binary-classification, multi-label-classification, multiclass-classification

I have billions of rows in some dataset and each row can be in any subset of about 1 million binary labels. So the number of overall classes would be $\sim 2^{1,000,000}$, if I were to think about it as a simple classification problem, which is obviously out of question due to feasibility. I am given the wonderful task to develop a model to assign new data into these 1m labels...

The first obvious thing to do is to train 1 model per label but then each model needs to be trained on each observation, and likewise, at the inference time, each model needs to run for each new observation. One improvement I can think of to make this solution somewhat more efficient is to use a hierarchical model structure so that not each of the 1m. models needs to see each observation:

1. 10 binary classifiers decide whether a data point belongs to 10 super-groups of classes.
2. 100 binary classifiers decide whether a data point belongs to 100 groups of classes, given that it belongs to the super-group that includes it.
3. 1,000,000 binary classifiers decide whether a data point belongs to any of these binary classes, given that it belongs to the higher level of the label hierarchy.

(Labels have some inherit hierarchy but it only has 2 levels as it is right now.)

So my idea is to build this so that a single neural network (in PyTorch) does all the work. Is there any recommendations for how to build this model and make my life easier?

What are good/feasible alternatives to the hierarchical approach I described?

Comment: Would you explain "binary label" and "binary class"? Do you mean your label is like 10011100?

Comment: Yes, each observation's label would be a sequence of length 1 million that consists of 1's and 0's, which is why I don't think it would be feasible to consider it as a simple classification problem.

Comment: Regarding subgroup, do you already know, which one in subgroup or you expect neural network could separate for you?

Comment: I already have a hierarchy on the labels so I don't need the NN to cluster them or anything like that. They are divided into 10 groups and 100 subgroups.